# To override the contents of files

Tags: linux, command-line, sed, awk, perl

I have two files, `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`, `file1.txt` is:

```
perimeter a=10
perimeter b=15
perimeter c=20
```

`file2.txt` is:

```
perimeter a=12
perimeter b=14
```

Let me know the `sed` or Perl to override the values in `file1.txt`

Output of `file1.txt` should be like:

```
perimeter a=12
perimeter b=14
perimeter c=20
```

I have used series of command like

```
sed -i -e '/parameter//d r file1.txt' file2.txt
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next;}a[$1]{$0=a[$1]}1' file1.txt file2.txt
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next;}a[$1]{$0=a[$1]}1' file2.txt file1.txt
```

None of these are helping.

Comment: Is `perimeter` vs `/parameter//d` a typo?

Comment: Your 2nd awk command is *almost* right, you're just using the wrong field separator: use `=` instead of `,`

Comment: Typo. It has to be permiter.!!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe? Save this as e.g. `script.pl` and run via `perl script.pl file1.txt file2.txt` and it produces your desired output. I've made some assumptions about the file format, such as that there are no blank lines or comments you need to preserve.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Tie::IxHash;

tie my %hash, 'Tie::IxHash';
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my ($k,$v) = split /=/, $_, 2;
    $hash{$k} = $v;
}
for my $k (keys %hash) {
    print "$k=$hash{$k}\n";
}
```

---

*Update:* A version without the dependency on [`Tie::IxHash`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::IxHash):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my (%hash, @keys);
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my ($key,$value) = split /=/, $_, 2;
    push @keys, $key unless exists $hash{$key};
    $hash{$key} = $value;
}
for my $key (@keys) {
    print "$key=$hash{$key}\n";
}
```

That can also be smushed into a oneliner:

```
perl -F= -anle 'exists$h{$F[0]}||push@k,$F[0];$h{$F[0]}=$F[1];END{print"$_=$h{$_}"for@k}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

*However* note that unlike the script, this oneliner won't work correctly if there are lines with more than one `=`.

Comment: It is printing perfectly,but when i try to append to file1.txt. i am unable to retain perimeter c =20. I am getting output as perimeter a=12
perimeter b=14 . I have used  perl -F= -anle 'exists$h{$F[0]}||push@k,$F[0];$h{$F[0]}=$F[1];END{print"$_=$h{$_}"for@k}' file1.txt file2.txt >file1.txt

Comment: If you're trying to do `perl ... file1.txt file2.txt >file1.txt` then yes, that won't work. See [How can I use a file in a command and redirect output to the same file without truncating it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6696842) - for example, try `perl ... file1.txt file2.txt | sponge file1.txt`, that seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to be a bit careful about how to actually rewrite the file. Don't do this:

```
some_program < file1 > file1
```

Because the shell takes care of the redirections *before* launching the program, the `>` redirection will **truncate** the file *before* the program gets a chance to read it.

Here are some alternatives:

1. explicitly write to a temp file, then overwrite the original

   ```
   tmpfile=$(mktemp)
   some_program < file1 > "$tmpfile" && mv "$tmpfile" file1
   ```

   Use `&&` so you only `mv` **if** the program exited successfully.
2. use the `sponge` command from the [`moreutils`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/moreutils) package

   ```
   some_program < file1 | sponge file1
   ```
3. If you're using GNU awk, you can use the `-i inplace` extension, but you need to adjust the program a bit:

   ```
   gawk -i inplace -F= '
       NR == FNR {a[$1] = $0; print; next} 
       $1 in a {$0 = a[$1]} 
       1
   ' file{2,1}.txt
   ```

Options 2 and 3 use a temp file as well, but will take care of the details for you.